# Layout for phone and tablet android

Tags: android

I have been searching for this thing and I have followed the documentation of Android in Supporting Multiple Screens. I have my phone which is mdpi and is 320x480. I also have my tablet which is mdpi and is 600x976. I have an image(320x581) in my drawable-mdpi/myimg.png and same image but bigger one(640x1162) in my drawable-hdpi/myimg.png. I also have layout/mylayout.xml and layout-large/mylayout.xml. So my question is, why does my tablet do not show the fullscreen image since I am expecting that the image will cover the whole screen? Any help would be much appreciated.
Below is my code for my layout for both layout/mylayout.xml and layout-large/mylayout.xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/myimg"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Depends on how your layout looks? if your layout limits to a certain width for instance...

Comment: You need to give dome code example from your layouts.

Comment: ` I have my phone which is mdpi and is 320x480. I also have my tablet which is mdpi and is 600x976` - so how do you expect it to pick an image from the hdpi folder since both devices are `mdpi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What made this to happen is to add drawable-large folder for the images for tablet.

Answer (score 0):

```
//for phone 
use layout folder(for both land and portrait mode)
//for tablet(7-inch)
use layout-sw600dp-land(for landscape)
use layout-sw600dp-port(for portrait)
//for tablet(10-inch)
use layout-sw720dp-land(for landscape)
use layout-sw7200dp-port(for portrait)

and draq 9-patch images using 
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @iCodeAtAndroid. But I was not able to make what I want to happen. I don't want to use match_parent for width and height of myimg because I don't want it to look pixelated. So since my tablet(600x976) is an mdpi, does that mean that the only images that my tablet use are the images from the drawable-mdpi folder?